# Nested IMessageQueueClient publish using Servicestack InMemoryTransientMessageService

Tags: servicestack, messaging, publish-subscribe

We are using InMemoryTransientMessageService to chain several one-way notification between services. We can not use Redis provider, and we do not really need it so far. Synchronous dispatching is enough.

We are experimenting problems when using a publish inside a service that is handling another publish. In pseudo-code:

FirstService.Method()
    _messageQueueClient.Publish(obj);

SecondService.Any(obj)
    _messageQueueClient.Publish(obj);

ThirdService.Any(obj)

The SecondMessage is never handled. In the following code of ServiceStack TransientMessageServiceBase, when the second message is processed, the service "isRunning" so it does not try to handled the second:

```
public virtual void Start()
    {
        if (isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;

        this.messageHandlers = this.handlerMap.Values.ToList().ConvertAll(
            x => x.CreateMessageHandler()).ToArray();

        using (var mqClient = MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
        {
            foreach (var handler in messageHandlers)
            {
                handler.Process(mqClient);
            }
        }

        this.Stop();
    }
```

I'm not sure about the impact of changing this behaviour in order to be able to nest/chain message publications. Do you think it is safe to remove this check? Some other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, it seems there is no problem in removing the "isRunning" control. All nested publications are executed correctly.